# Add pivot data from the same pivot model

Tags: beginner, php, laravel

My project has thee models `Cart`, `Order` and `Product`

`Cart` and `Order` have the same fields for pivot model

```
    class Cart extends Model {
            ...
            
            public function products() {
                    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot([
                            'id',
                            'count',
                            'price',
                            'discount',
                            'tax',
                            'created_at',
                            'updated_at'
                    ]);
            }
            
    }


    class Order extends Model {
            ...
            
            public function products() {
                    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot([
                            'id',
                            'count',
                            'price',
                            'discount',
                            'tax',
                            'created_at',
                            'updated_at'
                    ]);
            }
            
    }
```

How better create `Order` with pivot from `Cart` with pivot?

Now I have next code

```
    $cart = Cart::getCartFromSession();
    $order = Order::create($request->all());

    foreach ($cart->products as $product) {
        $order->products()->attach($product, [
            'count' => $product->pivot->count,
            'price' => $product->pivot->price,
            'discount' => $product->pivot->discount,
            'tax' => $product->pivot->tax,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Are `Cart` and `Pivot` related at all? e.g. would it make sense for one to be a sub-class of the other? or do they have completely separate implementations other than the `products` relation? Please add the rest of the models, since [65535 characters is allowed on CR posts](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7163/120114)